# Как данные с трёх полей собрать в одно сообщение на Email?

Tags: html, python, django

[image: У меня есть картинка, на которой есть 3 поля ввода, я разобрался как добавить одно поле в send_email, но как добавить 3 не могу понять, массивы пробовал, перечислять тоже.]

Вот как я беру с одного поля

```
def send_email(request):
   subject = 'Новая заявка!'
   message = request.POST.get('name_field')
   email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
   recipient_list = ['warglok@gmail.com', ]
   send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
   return HttpResponse("Successful")
```

А вот и собственно сама форма:

```
<form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ваше имя: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" name="name_field" placeholder="Петров Петр">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <label class="col-form-label" for="team_name">Номер или Email </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="team_name" type="text" name="name_field2"
                                           placeholder="+375299999999 или Email@gmail.com">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Сообщение: </label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" name="name_field3"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

самое простое это сделать так. В `message` поместить все что вам нужно и передать ее в `send_mail`. `'\n'` для переноса на новую строку в сообщении

```
def send_email(request):
   subject = 'Новая заявка!'
   message = 'имя' + request.POST.get('name_field') + '\n' + 'телефон\email'+request.POST.get('name_field2')+'\n'+'сообщение'+request.POST.get('name_field3')
   email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
   recipient_list = ['warglok@gmail.com', ]
   send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
   return HttpResponse("Successful")
```